# check if user subscription for trial period is expire or not using spring MVC

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

I am using spring MVC and want to check if user's trial period has expired.

I am getting user detail using spring security using the following method

```
  public User getUserDetail() {
    Authentication auth = SecurityContextHolder.getContext()
            .getAuthentication();   
    Object principal = auth.getPrincipal();
        if(principal instanceof User){
            User user = (User) principal;               
            return user;
        }
        return null;
}
```

User object contains the date when he logged in first.

I am checking the user subscription using following code

```
   UserBean userLoggedIn = (UserBean) userService.getUserDetail();

    Date dt =  userLoggedIn.getUserCreationDate();

    DateTime userCreated =  new DateTime(dt).plusDays(TRIAL_PERIOD);

    DateTime currentDateTime = new DateTime();


    if(currentDateTime.compareTo(userCreated) > 0 && userLoggedIn.getPackageType() == 0){
        return new ModelAndView("pricing","user",userLoggedIn);
    }
```

Now my problem is I don't want to write the above code repeatedly in each controller. So is there any common place where I can check the user trial period expire or not and redirect him to pricing page.

I have CustomUserDetail class where I am accessing user details from database and put it in spring security session. So I think this should be the best place to check if users trial period is expire or not but I don't know how I can redirect user from this class to pricing page.

My CustomUserDetail class is

```
  @Service
  @Transactional(readOnly = true)
 public class CustomUserDetailsService implements UserDetailsService {

static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(CustomUserDetailsService.class);


@Resource(name="userService")
private UserService userService;

/* (non-Javadoc)
 * @see org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService#loadUserByUsername(java.lang.String)
 */
@Override
public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String email)
        throws UsernameNotFoundException, DataAccessException {
        try {

            boolean enabled = true;
            boolean accountNonExpired = true;
            boolean credentialsNonExpired = true;
            boolean accountNonLocked = true;

            UserBean domainUser = userService.getUserByName(email);     

            domainUser.isEnabled();
            domainUser.isAccountNonExpired();
            domainUser.isCredentialsNonExpired();
            domainUser.isAccountNonLocked();


    //Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> roles =  getAuthorities((long) domainUser.getRoleId());

    return domainUser;


    } catch (Exception e) {
        logger.error("Invalid Login.",e);
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}
```

**---updated---**

My spring-security.xml is

```
    <form-login login-page="/login.htm" 
                authentication-failure-url="/loginfailed.htm"
                authentication-failure-handler-ref="exceptionMapper"
                default-target-url="/index.htm" 
                always-use-default-target="true"/>

    <access-denied-handler error-page="/logout.htm"/>

    <logout invalidate-session="true" 
        logout-url="/logout.htm"
        success-handler-ref="userController"/>
 <remember-me user-service-ref="customUserDetailsService" key="89dqj219dn910lsAc12" use-secure-cookie="true"  token-validity-seconds="466560000"/>
 <session-management session-authentication-strategy-ref="sas"/>
</http>

<authentication-manager>
        <authentication-provider user-service-ref="customUserDetailsService">
                <password-encoder ref="customEnocdePassword" >
                    <salt-source user-property="email"/>
                </password-encoder>
        </authentication-provider>
</authentication-manager>   
<beans:bean id="customEnocdePassword" class="com.mycom.myproj.utility.CustomEnocdePassword" />

<beans:bean id="exceptionMapper" class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.ExceptionMappingAuthenticationFailureHandler" >
<beans:property name="exceptionMappings">
    <beans:map>
        <beans:entry key="your.package.TrialPeriodExpiredException" value="/pricing"/>
    </beans:map>
</beans:property>
</beans:bean>

<beans:bean id="sas"
  class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.session.ConcurrentSessionControlStrategy">
<beans:constructor-arg name="sessionRegistry" ref="sessionRegistry" />
<beans:property name="maximumSessions" value="3" />
```

**---update----**

Now what I did is

```
 <beans:bean id="authenticationProvider" class="org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider">
    <beans:property name="userDetailsService" ref="customUserDetailsService"/>
    <beans:property name="passwordEncoder" ref="customEnocdePassword"/>
    <beans:property name="preAuthenticationChecks" ref="expirationChecker"/>
</beans:bean>

<authentication-manager>
    <authentication-provider user-service-ref="authenticationProvider">
        <password-encoder ref="customEnocdePassword" >
               <salt-source user-property="email"/>
        </password-encoder>
    </authentication-provider>
</authentication-manager>

<!-- <authentication-manager>
        <authentication-provider user-service-ref="customUserDetailsService">
                <password-encoder ref="customEnocdePassword" >
                    <salt-source user-property="email"/>
                </password-encoder>
        </authentication-provider>
</authentication-manager> -->
<beans:bean id="expirationChecker" class="com.mycom.myproj.utility.UserTrialPeriodExpirationChecker" />
<beans:bean id="customEnocdePassword" class="com.mycom.myproj.utility.CustomEnocdePassword" />
```

now I am getting below error

```
 "Cannot convert value of type [org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider]
to required type [org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService] 
for property 'userDetailsService': no matching editors or conversion strategy found"
```

Comment: Have you considered making this functionality a `Filter` to add to your filter chain?

Comment: User must be authenticated on pricing page? If it's true then you can use a custom authentication success handler for redirect.

Comment: @Nicholas , could please you give me a small example how I can use Filters here as I tried to user interceptor but that was not working for me.

Comment: @Maksym I think if I use authentication in pricing page then again I have to call method for pricing page from each controller.

Comment: @user965884 Really, I am not the most familiar with Spring Security, but I have a basic understanding of how it works in general.  That said, I couldn't give a small example without spending a lot of time digging in, and that is time I should not be using while at work! :)

Comment: There are multiple ways to do this. @user965884, could you please provide two responses for two simple questions (to be able find more appropriate way): 1) Trial expiration must be checked during login or during each request (think about how long your session is and do you have remember me functionality)? 2) User must be authenticated on pricing page (it looks natural for me that you can use your account during payment)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could set a custom `UserDetailsChecker` on the `DaoAuthenticationProvider` that verifies the expiration date before authenticating the user.

The `<authentication-provider>` element in your config generates a `DaoAuthenticationProvider`, but there is no attribute on that element that would allow you to set its `preAuthenticationChecks` property. In order to work around this limitation of the namespace configuration, you will have to fall back to defining that provider as a normal bean:

```
<bean id="authenticationProvider" class="org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider">
    <property name="userDetailsService" ref="customUserDetailsService"/>
    <property name="passwordEncoder" ref="customEnocdePassword"/>
    <property name="preAuthenticationChecks" ref="expirationChecker"/>
</bean>
```

and refer to it by the id in the `<authentication-manager>` config:

```
<security:authentication-manager>
    <security:authentication-provider ref="authenticationProvider"/>
</security:authentication-manager>
```

The above referenced `expirationChecker` bean must implement `UserDetailsChecker` which is a call-back interface receiving the `UserDetails` object, where you could throw a specific exception if the user's trial period has expired:

```
public class UserTrialPeriodExpirationChecker implements UserDetailsChecker {
    @Override
    public void check(UserDetails user) {
        if( /* whatever way you check expiration */ ) {
            throw new TrialPeriodExpiredException();
        }

        if (!user.isAccountNonLocked()) {
            throw new LockedException("User account is locked");
        }

        if (!user.isEnabled()) {
            throw new DisabledException("User is disabled");
        }

        if (!user.isAccountNonExpired()) {
            throw new AccountExpiredException("User account has expired");
        }
    }
}
```

Note that the last three checks are not related to the expiration checking, but you have to have them here, as the default implementation (which is `AbstractUserDetailsAuthenticationProvider.DefaultPreAuthenticationChecks`) is now overridden by this class. Since the default implementation is a private inner class, you cannot simply extend it, but need to copy the code from there to prevent locked/disabled/etc. users from logging in.

Once you have all that in place, configure an `ExceptionMappingAuthenticationFailureHandler` that maps your `TrialPeriodExpiredException` to the URL of the pricing page, where the user should land.

```
<form-login authentication-failure-handler-ref="exceptionMapper" ... />

...

<bean id="exceptionMapper" class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.ExceptionMappingAuthenticationFailureHandler" >
    <property name="exceptionMappings">
        <map>
            <entry key="your.package.TrialPeriodExpiredException" value="/pricing"/>
        </map>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Comment: Hi Zagyi, Could you please also send me the overview of code to write in TrialPeriodExpiredException class. Thanks

Comment: It doesn't really matter, any subclass of `RuntimeException` would do it. The only use of it will be to match against its name in the `exceptionMapper`. Probably it would make sense though to extend from `AccountStatusException`. You can use any of the subclasses of that as a template for your `TrialPeriodExpiredException`.

Comment: Hi Zagyi, its working fine and redirecting me to pricing page but still there is one problem that I am able to open other pages using URL as domainUser object gets created. I have to do something with user authentication. Could you please explain me what you were trying to tell me about AbstractUserDetailsAuthenticationProvider.DefaultPreAuthenticationChecks as I didn't get this part

Comment: What I wanted to say is that by setting your own `PreAuthenticationChecks` that verifies the trial period, you overwrite the default behavior, which is implemented in the inner class mentioned. If you don't copy the logic from there into your custom implementation, then those checks won't be performed, consequently disabled/locked/etc. users will be able to authenticate.

Comment: Hi Zagyi, sorry to come back late. I still don't understand where this  PreAuthenticationChecks are so I have update my question spring-security.xml as I am not using PreAuthenticationChecks. Would you please help me how I can put that in my spring-security.xml if possible for you

Comment: Tried to explain it in more details, please see my updated and extended answer above.

Comment: Hi Zagyi, I tried to implement the above but now I am getting this error "Cannot convert value of type [org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider] to required type [org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService] for property 'userDetailsService': no matching editors or conversion strategy found"

Comment: Your config still has `<authentication-provider user-service-ref="...` instead of `<authentication-provider ref="...`. The difference is not negligible...